# VHDL: Signals get U value even though there is another value assigned

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I’m implementing IDEA algorithm using VHDL, I have a problem in my keygenerator module, when I run the simulator I get values U in all of the signals even though I assign other values to them.

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity keygenerator is
    Port ( round : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           keyout1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout3 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout4 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout5 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           keyout6 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end keygenerator;

architecture Behavioral of keygenerator is

  SIGNAL key0 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key1 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key2 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key3 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key4 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key5 : std_logic_vector (127 downto 0);
  SIGNAL key6 : std_logic_vector (95 downto 0);

  signal output : std_logic_vector (95 downto 0);


begin

  process (round, key)

  begin
    key0 <= key;
    key1 <= key0(102 downto 0) & key0(127 downto 103);
    key2 <= key1(102 downto 0) & key1(127 downto 103);
    key3 <= key2(102 downto 0) & key2(127 downto 103);
    key4 <= key3(102 downto 0) & key3(127 downto 103);
    key5 <= key4(102 downto 0) & key4(127 downto 103);
    key6 <= key5(102 downto 7); 

    case round is
      when "0000" => output <= key0(127 downto 32);
      when "0001" => output <= key0(31 downto 0) & key1(127 downto 64);
      when "0010" => output <= key1(63 downto 0) & key2(127 downto 96);
      when "0011" => output <= key2(95 downto 0);
      when "0100" => output <= key3(127 downto 32);
      when "0101" => output <= key3(31 downto 0) & key4(127 downto 64);
      when "0110" => output <= key4(63 downto 0) & key5(127 downto 96);
      when "0111" => output <= key5(95 downto 0);
      when "1000" => output <= key6;
      when others => output <= (others => 'X');
    end case;

  end process;

  keyout6 <= output(15 downto 0);
  keyout5 <= output(31 downto 16);
  keyout4 <= output(47 downto 32);
  keyout3 <= output(63 downto 48);
  keyout2 <= output(79 downto 64);
  keyout1 <= output(95 downto 80);

end Behavioral;
```

That's my testbench:

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY tb_keygenerator IS
END tb_keygenerator;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_keygenerator IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT keygenerator
    PORT(
         round : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         key : IN  std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
         keyout1 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout2 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout3 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout4 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout5 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         keyout6 : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal round : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal key : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) := (others => '0');

   --Outputs
   signal out1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out3 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out4 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out5 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   signal out6 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 

   constant I_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

  -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: keygenerator PORT MAP (
          round => round,
          key => key,
          keyout1 => out1,
          keyout2 => out2,
          keyout3 => out3,
          keyout4 => out4,
          keyout5 => out5,
          keyout6 => out6
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   I_process :process
   begin
    key <= X"12345678912345678912345678912345";
    round <="1100";
    wait for I_period/2;
    key <= X"12345678912345678912345678912345";
    round <="1001";
    wait for I_period/2;
   end process;


END;
```

Comment: It seems like you should get U's on the key0-6 for up to ~25 ns since the process only updates in simulation when "round" changes. "1100" and "1001" are not defined cases, so the output will always be X's.

Comment: You don't initialize the signals in RTL code, therefore the simulator  puts an U on them. Try to initialize them to (others =>'0') for example and then see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what it should.

You have 'output' defined as 'X' for rounds other than "0000" through to "1000". In your test bench you apply round "1100" and "1001".

However you say outputs are 'U' not 'X'.  I would guess this means that you have not compiled the entity.

Note, in your test bench you apply the key twice needlessly.